# Exchanging parts between two objects

Tags: modeling, mesh

*I'm making a prosthetic hand for a young man.  These are the 'gauntlet' and 'palm' for the base design:*

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7IZ4iPA1DJZWnVHN2RtdnB5WlU&usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7IZ4iPA1DJZWnVHN2RtdnB5WlU&usp=sharing

The two parts join at a "wrist hinge".  As designed, the forearm "gauntlet" hinge (link 1) is inside the "palm" hinge (Link 2).  However, there are many instances where the "gauntlet" hinge needs to be outside the palm hinge.

A) I've struggled to cut away the hinge from (2) to transfer to (1), but have not figured out how to reattach.  The hinges from (1) need to be transferred to (2).
B) Reattach the new hinges to the primary objects.
C) Offset the hinge connections on (2) about 2mm toward the center and spread the connections on (1) about 8mm away from the center of the object.

Okay, I hope A, B, & C convey what I'd like to accomplish.  However, I'm fairly certain that this is a relatively simple transformation in Blender.  I'm just too locked into conventional CAD.

*With a fresh cup of coffee, it occurs to me that this might effectively be accomplished by selecting each hinge in turn and translating it, then smoothing the vertices.  The holes for the hinge pins would require some reshaping, which I haven't learned.  So...different questions:  1) can the effects of the hinge translation be spread over more than adjacent vertices (smoothing enabled?) and 2) can a primitive be used to reshape the holes for the hinge pins?*

TIA for links, suggestions,....

Comment: AFAICT those links are identical, and I see a directory of some 30 files and a few subdirectories.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you included images of what you are trying to do as part of the question instead of links. Even better would be a single blend file.